# chrome extension get data from web site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

im trying to get data from web pages. I read lot of documents but still i couldnt do anything. I want to get title from a youtube video.
Basiclly my extension has just a click function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        alert("This youtube title: ");
    });
});
```

[youtube image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZByEo.png)

How can i get this title when i clicked button ?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail? Are you trying to get this data from the Youtube API, or from an embedded Youtube video on the page?

Comment: I'm opening the video page then i click the button to get the current playing video title. No api or something else.

Comment: Do you want to fetch youtube video title by its id?

Comment: No with the html source code like at this picture.
http://i66.tinypic.com/181zc8.png

Comment: With a chrome extension you need to look at the security policies because you need to edit the manifest to allow http requests to YouTube

Comment: And you'll want to look at the YouTube api for embedding YouTube with JavaScript

Comment: Wait. You're just trying to retrieve the title?  Your problem there is that it will require you searching through the current tabs Dom (which means you need to add tabs to the manifest I believe) and find where YouTube stores the text of the title in the Dom (which might change)

Comment: Im not working only on youtube it can be any different web site. I need to understand the main sense of get data from web page.

Comment: Look at the chrome extension api to access the Dom of a tab after that every web page is going to be different

Comment: `document.title.replace(" - YouTube", "")` anyone?

Answer (score 0):

declare **tabs** permission in manifest file then on button click add following code snippet

```
 chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function (tabs) {
       var current_tab = tabs[0];
       var url = current_tab.url;


})
```